# How to split table when page overflow?

Tags: jasper-reports

I am displaying data, using two nested tables in order to put the text in the middle of the category.
The "Fonction" is in the detail band, with a table displaying the "Modele" values. To put these values in the middle I put a second table in the first one, to print "Ligne", "Taille"...

 "Modele" can gather multiple "Ligne", which can be gathered by "Fonction":
[image: "Modele" can gather multiple "Ligne", which can be gathered by "Fonction"]

This is working fine, until a three lines table reaches the end of page. There, it does not split, and is diplayed on the next page :
[image: Here you can see that the "Fonction" reaches the bottom of the page as the detail band expands all the way down, but the first table is not splitted]

[image: The three lines table does not split, and prints on the next page]

How can I split this table to prevent getting a blank line?

Comment: Have similar problem... some could help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get this working by using a crosstab with row groups for the first three columns, and the other fields are put in the detail box
[image]

You must put these fields into mesures to be able to use them in the crosstab.